# Beamer and JavaScript in a web browser

Tags: beamer, html, svg, latex2html, javascript

I have written a talk in Beamer and to illustrate one of my points I've written a program in JavaScript (well actually [Processing](http://processing.org/)).  You can view it [here](http://www.personal.soton.ac.uk/jtg1g11/) (it seems to run ok in Chrome and Firefox, and indeed on my phone).  At the moment I <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> out of my presentation into Google Chrome when it comes to the relevant slide in my talk.  This isn't such a bad solution, but it's not a *nice* solution.

I would like to be able to export my slides into html/svg and then use some combination of JavaScript and HTML5 to view my slides in the browser.  Googling I wasn't able to find a well-documented approach to this, although there are a lot of snippets, mainly on this site.

Has anyone had success in doing this?  And if so what tools/path did you use?

Such an approach loses the *absolute* portability of the PDF format, but gains *practical* portability in the sense that I could show someone my slides on a tablet with all features intact.

Comment: Perhaps the output of [pdf2htmlEX](http://coolwanglu.github.com/pdf2htmlEX/) would be acceptable?

Comment: Isn't it possible to import this javascript interactive view within a pdf (with the media9 extension for instance)? This way, you would directly have it in your pdf document.

Comment: @pluton could you elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: @Bordaigorl Please see section 7 of media9's user guide [1]. The pdf format now supports .ud3 and .prc files that embeds objects that can be interactively manipulated within Adobe Reader (other pdf readers do not currently support these applications).
[1] http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/media9

Comment: @pluton thanks for the pointers; however I was hoping for a way to embed a browser viewport in the pdf, not a 3d format. These javascript generated pictures are interesting because they are highly interactive and generated on the fly from maybe live data or user input...

Answer (score 3):

dvisvgm could be a solution. It converts dvi files to svg files, see http://dvisvgm.sourceforge.net/