# Beamer equivalent of Keynote's old web view

Tags: beamer, html, javascript

Is there a beamer package that will display a non-static, locally hosted web page? I think I am looking for something similar to Keynote's old web view, but since I have Keynote 09, I'm in a pickle.

This question is similar to [Beamer and JavaScript in a web browser](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58805/beamer-and-javascript-in-a-web-browser), which currently does not have a satisfactory answer. Like this poster, I would prefer to not have to click on a link and navigate away from the presentation.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has no reasonable answer other than "no, there's not".

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: PDF files, which are produced by TeX (either directly or *via* DVI) do not have the possibility to show the type of dynamic content required here. This essentially requires a web rendered 'built in' or 'called' by the viewer, and that is not part of the PDF spec.